# Ruby Sanitize Code ... why is & sanitized 

Tags: ruby, sanitize

I currently use the following code to sanitize a string before storing them:

```
ERB::Util::h(string)
```

My problem occurs when the string has been sanitized already like this:

```
string = "Watching baseball `&amp;` football"
```

The sanitized string will look like:

```
sanitized_string = "Watching baseball `&amp;amp;` football"
```

Can I sanitize by just turning < into `&lt;` and > into `&gt;` via substitution?

Comment: Seems like a strange use case... do you sanitize things variable number of times? Otherwise, what's wrong with `&amp;amp;` if you know you will reverse it when you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unescape first, then escape again:

```
require 'cgi'
string = "Watching baseball &amp; football"

CGI.escapeHTML(CGI.unescapeHTML(string))

=> "Watching baseball &amp; football"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! .. I will try the unescape first answer.

Answer (score 0):

A fast approach based on [this snippet from Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.05.html).

```
ESCAPE_TABLE = { '<'=>'&lt;', '>'=>'&gt;' }
def custom_h(value)
   value.to_s.gsub(/[<>]/) { |s| ESCAPE_TABLE[s] }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, or taking it further you can just delete entire tags with a basic regex like this:

```
mystring.gsub( /<(.|\n)*?>/, '' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own sanitizer, but there are lots of corner cases and tricky edges in sanitization.

A better approach might be to unencode your string before sanitizing it - does h() have an inverse you could put your strings through first?